# Why task processing serial in flink

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-flink

[image]

```
//抓包
DataStream<byte[]> logSource = env.addSource(new PacpParalleSourceFunction()).setParallelism(CAPTURE_PACKAGE_PARALLELISM);

//解析
XmlLogParse xmlLogParse = new XmlLogParse();
DataStream<JSONObject> objectDataStream = logSource.map(new Log2ObjFunction(xmlLogParse)).setParallelism(PARSE_LOG_PARALLELISM);


//写csv   The parallelism of non parallel operator must be 1
LogStorage logStorage = new WriteFileStorage();
objectDataStream.countWindowAll(ConstantField.BATCH_DEAL_COUNT).apply(
        new AllWindowFunction<JSONObject, Object, GlobalWindow>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(GlobalWindow globalWindow, Iterable<JSONObject> iterable, Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {
                ArrayList<JSONObject> list = Lists.newArrayList(iterable);
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    logStorage.doStorage(list);
                    logger.info("写入文件  " + list.size() + " 耗时" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        }
).name("out put to csv").setParallelism(1);


//写kafka
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_HOST);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("topic", KAFKA_DST_TOPIC_NAME);
DataStreamSink<JSONObject> obj2kafka = objectDataStream.addSink(new KafkaSinkFunction(props)).setParallelism(WRITE_KAFKA_PARALLELISM);

obj2kafka.name("output2kafka");

// execute application
env.execute("elksoc-log4p");
```

How can I make these two tasks parallel?
How can I make these two tasks parallel?
How can I make these two tasks parallel?
How can I make these two tasks parallel?
How can I make these two tasks parallel?
How can I make these two tasks parallel?
How can I make these two tasks parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use Side Outputs, for more information see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/